# Disable Anti Aliasing in Qt3D

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

We are migrating from an older 3D engine to Qt 3D. In order to compare the older 3D engine with Qt3D I'm writing a small app, that compares both renderings side to side.

In order to make an automatic comparision more suitable I'm in need to deactive anti aliasing in Qt3D.

I think, that I have to modify the frame graph, but I have no idea, what is necessary to do this.

The following example app shows a simple Qt3D Scene with a sphere. Does anyone know how to perform the necessary changes in the default frame graph?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QFrame>
#include <Qt3DRender/QCamera.h>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QSphereMesh>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QDiffuseSpecularMaterial>
#include <Qt3DExtras/qforwardrenderer.h>
#include <Qt3DExtras/Qt3DWindow.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    auto view = new Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow();
    auto frameGraph = view->defaultFrameGraph();
    frameGraph->setClearColor(QColor(255,255,255));
    // Disable Anti-Aliasing
    // What is necessary here!
    // ---------------------

    auto rootEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity();
    view->setRootEntity(rootEntity);

    auto cameraEntity = view->camera();
    cameraEntity->lens()->setPerspectiveProjection(45.0f, 1., 0.1f, 10000.0f);
    cameraEntity->setPosition(QVector3D(5, 5, 5));
    cameraEntity->setUpVector(QVector3D(0, 1, 0));
    cameraEntity->setViewCenter(QVector3D(0, 0, 0));

    auto mesh = new Qt3DExtras::QSphereMesh();
    mesh->setRadius(1.);

    auto meshMaterial = new Qt3DExtras::QDiffuseSpecularMaterial();
    meshMaterial->setAlphaBlendingEnabled(true);
    meshMaterial->setDiffuse(QColor(50, 50, 50));
    meshMaterial->setAmbient(QColor(255, 255, 255));
    meshMaterial->setSpecular(QColor(255,255,255));
    meshMaterial->setShininess(100);

    auto meshEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);
    meshEntity->addComponent(mesh);
    meshEntity->addComponent(meshMaterial);
    meshEntity->setEnabled(true);

    auto container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view);
    QFrame frame;
    frame.setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
    frame.layout()->addWidget(container);

    frame.setFixedSize(500, 500);
    frame.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure antialiasing is enabled? Looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51331270/add-qmultisampleantialiasing-to-a-qforwardrenderer) it looks like you have to add a [QMultiSampleAntiAliasing class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qmultisampleantialiasing.html) to your framegraph.

Comment: @Florian Blume: Yes it is enabled. You might confirm by running the app. Maybe this is a default behaviour.

Comment: That's weird. You should need a multi sample node but the `Qt3DWindow` doesn't add one. Maybe try setting your own format (see the window's code on GitHub how to do so).

Comment: @FlorianBlume: You mean the `QWindow` implementation? Actually, I tried to set the format, but there was no effect after all. But setting `setStereo(true)` disabled the anti-aliasing. I just posted this `working solution` as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Qt Docs for [multisampleantialiasing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt3d-render-multisampleantialiasing.html)
There is some example code there.

EDIT: addendum

**QML Scene3D has the following property**

**multisample : bool**

> true if a multisample render buffer is requested. By default
>   multisampling is enabled. If the OpenGL implementation has no support
>   for multisample renderbuffers or framebuffer blits, the request to use
>   multisampling is ignored. Note: Refrain from changing the value
>   frequently as it involves expensive and potentially slow
>   initialization of framebuffers and other OpenGL resources.

But there is no counterpart of Scene3D for the C++ world... Most QML classes have a counterpart for C++ by adding a "Q" in front of the name. But there is no QScene3D.

**Remark about the usage of Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow**

Qt3DWindow is derived from QWindow and was created to have solutions without the use of QWidgets. You can read more about the details [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860604/what-is-the-difference-between-a-qwindow-and-qwidget)

If you want to add buttons, sliders, ets... in a later testing stage, I would advise using QML. You will get more flexibility from Qt3D compared to using C++ solely. It is even possible to mix C++ and QML: you can make your logic in C++ and register for usage in QML. So you get the best of both worlds. That is what I would do if I wanted to test the Qt3D capabilities thoroughly.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

If anyone stumbles across this, how I can enable/disable antialising in Qt3D is by setting the number of samples on the surface format:

```cpp
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setSamples(0); // Disables anti-aliasing
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
```

```cpp
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setSamples(4); // Enables 4x anti-aliasing
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
```

This has to happen before setting up Qt3D.

**NB:** This is for when you want to disable/enable antialiasing in a default Qt3D scene, i.e. where you don't render to a texture and then use it in a shader. If you want to do the latter, check out `QMultiSampleAntiAliasing`.

Comment: you again. Well, I'm not surprised!

Answer (score 1):

The following code disables the anti-aliasing, but is definitely not the correct way to do it. But, after all I got to a working solution. Setting `setStereo(true)` in the `QSurfaceFormat` disabled the anti-aliasing magically.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QFrame>
#include <Qt3DRender/QCamera>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QSphereMesh>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QDiffuseSpecularMaterial>
#include <Qt3DExtras/qforwardrenderer>
#include <Qt3DExtras/Qt3DWindow>
#include <Qt3DRender/QRenderSettings>

void depthFirstTraversal(const Qt3DRender::QFrameGraphNode* node, int depth) {
    auto pad = QString(depth, QChar('\t'));
    qDebug().noquote().nospace() <<  pad << node;
    for (auto iter : node->children()) {
        if (auto frameGraphNode = qobject_cast<Qt3DRender::QFrameGraphNode*>(iter)) {
            depthFirstTraversal(frameGraphNode, depth + 1);
        }       
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setStereo(true); // Disables anti-aliasing, but is definitely weird
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    auto view = new Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow();
    auto frameGraph = view->activeFrameGraph();
    depthFirstTraversal(frameGraph, 0);
    view->defaultFrameGraph()->setClearColor(QColor(255,255,255));

    auto rootEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity();
    view->setRootEntity(rootEntity);

    auto cameraEntity = view->camera();
    cameraEntity->lens()->setPerspectiveProjection(45.0f, 1., 0.1f, 10000.0f);
    cameraEntity->setPosition(QVector3D(5, 5, 5));
    cameraEntity->setUpVector(QVector3D(1, 1, 0));
    cameraEntity->setViewCenter(QVector3D(0, 0, 0));

    auto mesh = new Qt3DExtras::QSphereMesh();
    mesh->setRadius(1.);

    auto meshMaterial = new Qt3DExtras::QDiffuseSpecularMaterial();
    meshMaterial->setAlphaBlendingEnabled(true);
    meshMaterial->setDiffuse(QColor(50, 50, 50));
    meshMaterial->setAmbient(QColor(255, 255, 255));
    meshMaterial->setSpecular(QColor(255,255,255));
    meshMaterial->setShininess(100);

    auto meshEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);
    meshEntity->addComponent(mesh);
    meshEntity->addComponent(meshMaterial);
    meshEntity->setEnabled(true);

    auto container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view);
    QFrame frame;
    frame.setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
    frame.layout()->addWidget(container);

    frame.setFixedSize(500, 500);
    frame.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```